# Error while trying to import Blogger Posts into Octopress/Jekyll

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, blogger, jekyll

I wanted to switch my main blog to Octopress earlier today and so, I cloned Octopress, configured it and deployed it in Heroku.

Then I searched the net on how to import my old blogger posts into Octopress and found this script as the answer to it:

https://gist.github.com/1578928

I have the exported `blog.xml` file with me. When I run the script in the gist, I get the following error. I've just started with Ruby and I don't know much about it. I would be glad if anyone could help me with this. The error seems completely new and I couldn't find any answers to this from my searches so far.

```
    import.rb:33:in `add': dunno ide (RuntimeError)
    from import.rb:158:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
    from import.rb:157:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the script in the Gist you linked, the problem is that it can only parse 'post' and 'comment' types, while you seem to have another one called 'ide'.

You should double check if the output XML is all right and doesn't have strangely named tags.

Comment: The XML is fine and I couldn't find any type called "ide" in it, except in a post, which I don't think would be of any problem here.

Comment: I'm not sure how this XML looks like (if you don't mind posting at least some of it that would help), but this is how the script works out the `type`: `type = node.search('category').first.attr('term').split('#').last`. So essentially it's parsing `category` terms and expects to find either `post` or `comment` to do something meaningful, or `template`, `settings` to silently ignore. Oh and all these happen within `entry` nodes.

Comment: I have the same problem using blogger, [import.rb gist](https://gist.github.com/dnagir/1765496) script and octopress.

* **Avoid** to raise the exception in ruby:`else  raise 'dunno '+type`
* **or** remove comments from your exported blogger xml.

Comment: The fixed version is [here](https://gist.github.com/thefourtheye/f244735007801bf8c020ccce8ec10eaf)